# How to add custom fee block in total block checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, onestepcheckout, custom-block, extrafee

I have two custom modules. One is onestepcheckout and another is for a custom fee. 
I need to add a customs fee block into the onestepcheckout.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the list of link. You can try any of the one.

https://github.com/tobidsn/paymentrandomfee

https://blog.magestore.com/magento-custom-total-models/

It may help you.